# The set of all polynomials in $F[x,y]$ having constant term $0$ is an ideal, but not a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In Fraleigh, it said,

> "Consider the set N of all polynomials in x and y in F[x,y] having constant term 0. Then N is an ideal, but not a principal ideal." (p.399)

Could you tell me why this is not a principal ideal?

Comment: Do you mean "***why*** this is not a principal ideal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $N$ contains both the polynomials $x$ and $y$; is there any element of $F[x, y]$ dividing both $x$ and $y$ that is *not* a constant?

Answer (score 4):

Assume $N$ is a principal ideal $=(f)$. Then $x$ and $y \in N$ so there is some $r$ and $s$, with $rf=x$ and $sf=y$. By considering the $x$ degree and the $y$ degree, we can see $f$ must be in our field. Then $N=F[x,y]$ or $0$, both of which are absurd.